# 0403-057 Syntax error at line 54: `(' is not expected

Tags: bash, oracle11g, ksh

```
arr=(`${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlplus -s "${user}"/"${pass}"@ID <<EOF
    set heading off
    select distinct name from backup;
    exit;
    EOF`)
```

While executing the script in AIX 7.1 getting below error.

> 0403-057 Syntax error at line 54: `(' is not expected.

In RHEL , it works fine.
I need to store the query result in an array named arr.
Could you please suggest any pointers.

Comment: Make sure you are running the script through `bash` or `ksh` and not through `/bin/sh` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your here document terminator - it must start in column zero and be on its own on a line.

```
arr=($(${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/sqlplus -s "${user}"/"${pass}"@ID <<EOF
    set heading off
    select distinct name from backup;
    exit;
EOF
))
```

Note that this syntax for an array is not supported by ksh88, make sure you are using bash or ksh93.  Also, back-ticks are deprecated, try not to use them.